# What is the most efficient way to compile a solution with multiple dependent projects?

Tags: development, visual-studio

I currently have a solution with one "active" project and several helper projects. These projects represent different utility libraries used within my team. The benefit is that the libraries are kept up to date with the different projects that use them. The cost is that when I make a change in my project and recompile, all the projects in the solution are recompiled which is starting to take a long time.

I attempted to create a build configuration (DEBUG_SP) that only built the active project but I think that was a misuse of its purpose and it didn't work anyways.

**Question**

What is the most efficient way to compile a solution with multiple dependent projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can right click on solution and click on properties and then go to Configuration and create build configurations. You can include or exclude projects that you want to build in particular build configuration.

Answer (score 0):

[This site here](http://arnosoftwaredev.blogspot.dk/2010/05/how-to-improve-visual-studio-compile.html) offers some tips to what can be done.

I noticed point 2

```
(2) Prevent non-dependent project compilation

If a solution contains projects, that the current startup project does not depend upon         
(e.g. test projects), compiling those projects can be avoided by selecting the option 
"Only build startup projects and dependencies on Run" under Tools / Options / Projects  
and Solutions / Build and Run.
```